# Hierarchical Operation Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

Clearly I'm missing something simple but I don't know what. I would like to propagate an operation by groups. Let's say something simple, I have a simple series with multiindex (let's say 2 levels), I want to take the mean and subtract that mean to the correct index level.

Minimalist example code:

```py
a = pd.Series({(2,1): 3., (1,2):4.,(2,3):4.})
b = a.groupby(level=0).mean()
r = a-b # this is the wrong line, b doesn't propagate to the multiindex of a
```

The result that I expect:

```
2  1    -0.5
1  2    0
2  3    .5
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with possible defined level for align:

```
r = a.sub(b, level=0)
print (r)
2  1   -0.5
1  2    0.0
2  3    0.5
dtype: float64
```

Or use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same index like original `a Series`:

```
b = a.groupby(level=0).transform('mean')
r = a-b
print (r)
2  1   -0.5
1  2    0.0
2  3    0.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: by the way @jezrael, I might need to post another question, but let's say that the result of `b` is also multilevel (e.g. if `a` has 3 levels and `b` has 2 levels because `b= a.groupby(level=[0,1]).mean()`), this seems not to work any more. If I'm not clear enough, either I update my question or post a new one. But what I would be expecting would be something like `r = a.sub(b, level=[0,1])` which doesn't seem to work. I get `TypeError: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous `

Comment: ok, didn't check your 2nd example with the `transform` function, that's what work in that case =)